# Block URL address in htaccess regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, block

I want block this URL in `.htaccess`:

```
example.com/cart.php?a=checkout
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=checkout$
RewriteRule ^cart\.php$ - [F]
```

This blocks (403 Forbidden) the *exact* URL `example.com/cart.php?a=checkout` (as stated).

Notes:

- The first condition specifically matches the hostname `example.com` (as stated in the question), so would exclude any www subdomain. Remove this condition to match *any* hostname.
- If there are any other characters in the query string then access will be permitted. To match the URL parameter *anywhere* in the query string (and any case) then change the 2nd condition to read:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \ba=checkout\b [NC]
  ```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

---

If you are on Apache 2.4 then you can use an Apache Expression instead.

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/cart.php' && %{QUERY_STRING} == 'a=checkout'">
Require all denied
</If>
```

Comment: I want user FilesMatch regext because I want block URL for specific country.

`<FilesMatch "^(REGEX)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: There's no "specific country" in the example URL in your question? But you can't use a `FilesMatch` directive to match against the query string - which is part of the URL in your question? What version of Apache are you on? `Order` and `Deny` directives are Apache 2.2 (and earlier), it is more likely you are on Apache 2.4? Please edit your question to add the necessary information.

Comment: I want Edit this code
`<FilesMatch "^(cart\.php)$">`
for this regex:
`cart.php?a=checkout`

now check "cart.php" but I want check "cart.php?a=checkout"

Comment: You can't. As I said above, you can't use the `<FilesMatch>` directive to match against the query string part of the URL. `FilesMatch` matches against the _filename_ only. To match the query string then you either need to use mod_rewrite (as stated in my answer) or use Apache Expressions on Apache 2.4.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add more notes (to match any host and to match the URL parameter anywhere in the query string). I've also added an alternative approach using an Apache Expression on Apache 2.4+